# Delta Updating, what it is, how to implement it, where is it found?

Tags: c#, software-updates

I am not sure where this is going to go, and I am not sure if this is even the right Stack group to be posting in for this matter. But simply I want to create from scratch using my knowledge of C# a means of updating a program using Delta Updating.

So firstly some background, I want to create an app store (totally hypothetical) that will supply programs written in C#. The only application I will provide is the Store or Downloader/Updater program. The system will have some database and file storage to store all the versions of each application. To better supply updates to users when an app is updated is to provide Delta Updating. Information found here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_update).

Given the background I have some options, I could simply install Git with my Store and create Git Repos when a user downloads a new app. Using Git on both the update server and the user's system I could perform Diff functions and determine which files needs to be updated, etc. However, I thought wouldn't it be fun to create this diff system entirely on my own in C# just because why not?

So I am having a lot of trouble finding information about Delta Updating other than that 1 article that explains really simply what it is. I don't want to spend a lot of time on this project because it is really just a fun learning experience for me.

Can anyone provide some better knowledge on Delta Updating, like some basic understanding of how it can perform diff across many version changes, like client version of app at 1, server version of app at 3+. How can the server return only the section of bytes required to change and what kind of meaningful data structure could I maintain that information in. Are there any C# libraries out there today that already do this? How popular is this updating technique in terms of the Google Play Store, Apple Store, etc?

Comment: Are you just looking at it for use on mobile app stores? As the wikipedia page you referenced mentions, this is actually already built into both the Google Play and Apple App stores. It's generally a responsibility of the app distribution platform to handle this, so you wouldn't generally want to built something like this yourself, unless you plan to want to create your own distribution channel? As a starting point, you could use a unix tool like [BSDiff](https://github.com/mendsley/bsdiff), which calculates diffs on binary files.

Comment: I know they're used on distribution platforms I am wondering to what degree, is there better implementations of it, how would one go about creating their own system using this.

Comment: It's a really neat updating technique but I have found very little in terms of how it works under the hood and how to implement a system using it. I am not looking to write a fully functional app store but I want to create a minor system using this updating technique.

Comment: Asking for 3rd party resources is off topic for this site, and even if you would remove that part from your question, I am pretty sure your question would be closed as "too broad". However, you may start with "binary diff algorithms", have a look [here](http://wiki.c2.com/?DiffAlgorithm)

Comment: ... the [rsync algorithm](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/) may be what you are looking for,